# How to remove last character from StringVar in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to delete the last character of a StringVar using `(StringVar name) = (StringVar name)[:-1]` But it says **TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable** so is there a way I can delete the last character of a StringVar ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the string inside `StringVar` using `.get()` and use `.set()` to reassign it.

```
name.set(name.get()[:-1])
```